# How to make a 20-field online form more user friendly?

Tags: forms, ux-field

I've made a pretty basic form for data entry that will be used by office workers to build a database. The form is actually a composite of a decade of excel files that the organization has been using, which is one reason there are so many fields. Another problem is that the form is covering 2 different types of entry - there are "subscribers" and there are "contributors", but the manager insists absolutely that there be only 1 form that handles both and that all fields remain editable (so no hiding fields until they are needed).

So, right now I have 2 columns of fields - 1 column that has physical information (name, address, fax number, etc.) and 1 column that has meta information (email address, account notes, etc..)

Is this the best layout considering the restrictions that I have?

here's a link to what I've got so far:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot rather than a link to a live site.

Comment: Also, the fields do have a gentle highlight when they are active, so there's that much at least.

Comment: Have you considered mapping the form against a rotating 3d cube?

Comment: A slight side issue, but the whole idea of breaking a name into First/Middle/Last pieces is very western thinking. Better to use Name/Family/KnownAs - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/259694/30280 for more.

Comment: "the manager insists absolutely that there be only 1 form that handles both" - that constraint is hindering the user experience of the task right off the bat. I would suggest getting to the bottom of this constraint and possibly eliminating it if it turns out to be irrelevant. Use the technique of [laddering](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2009/07/laddering-a-research-interview-technique-for-uncovering-core-values.php) - basically continuing to ask clarifying questions in order to get to the root considerations behind this decision.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I mocked up a version of the form in HTML that I think improves a couple of things (but not all, because I'm not you and don't know your specific domain issues):

http://newlyminted.handcraft.com/

[image]

Some of the changes I made:

- **Group related fields**. First name, middle name and last name are part of the same flow, so group them together visually. Same goes for things like address, etc.
- **Split up the form into fieldsets**. This breaks things up and allows me to deal with one part of the form at a time, and simultaneously makes the form feel less long since I don't have to grok the whole thing at once.
- **Use a dropdown for state**. This prevents errors and just makes things easier overall. I also reduced the size of the zip code field since you know it'll never be more than 5 characters. One upside here is that the field now has some kind of affordance because I can intuitively identify it as a zip code field purely on size.
- **Use the right input controls where relevant**. Like the select for states above, I made the Notes field a textarea since "notes" by its nature implies that you'll want to input more information than fits in a single input field, and scrolling back and forth in those things sucks.

Hope that helps. Feel free to reuse.

Comment: One thing I would consider would be to keep all or most fields in the same column vertically.  This will create a much taller page, but users are more accustomed to scrolling nowadays and this will keep the flow of input more consistent.

Comment: Grouping related fields is one of the most important UI features, so glad you mentioned it.

Comment: As a general rule about state dropdowns, be sure to handle international addresses. Quite often web forms will assume that everyone lives in an American state even if they have a country field in the form that differs.

Comment: Related to zzzzBov's comment; you can't assume a postal code is always 5 characters long.

Comment: +1/1 for an awesome answer and question. A little addendum; you should let the user know if fields are mandatory OR optional (whichever are fewer) some fields may not apply to some and everything a user has to enter detracts from the UX.

Comment: Suggested change: make Address 1&2 full width and put them one on top of the other, not side by side, since that's how it would be printed.

Comment: This is a great answer and makes the two main changes I'd have considered (fieldsets and labels on top), but I think there are a few minor changes I'd be inclined to make: (1) Variable-width form fields would go a long way to making it more readable. Especially things like the middle name/initial, but even things like the email addresses. (2) I think address one and two should be shown over two lines, with "Address" as the label and "Address One" and "Address Two" being shown as placeholder text. (3) Contributor and Subscriber should be radio buttons to remove the need for the awkward label.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to hear about your constraints. The No.1 problem in this form's usability is the manager who wants to merge 2 workflows into one form.

Here's what you need to do to relieve the situation a bit:

1. Split the form into multiple steps (at least "Contact info" and "Payment info"). If that's not possible create visually separate sections on one page and label & number them: "Contact Details - 1/4" (or whatever).
2. Since it's a long vertical form, top-align labels to increase speed of completion.
3. Shorten label names that currently are 2 rows.
4. Remove default values from the drop-downs - they should be blank on load.
5. If the drop-downs are no more than 3 options, change them to radio buttons and place them vertically - faster recognition.
6. Align "Submit" button with the text fields not labels.

For general information on form design, see Smashing Magazine's "[An Extensive Guide To Web Form Usability](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/08/extensive-guide-web-form-usability/)" and the articles & books linked in it.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll be doing quite a bit of reading from here.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that springs to mind is that you have one form for both Contributors and Subscribers.

Split the form into three parts:

- Common fields
- Subscriber fields
- Contributor fields

Ideally you'd only show the subscriber or contributor fields when that type of user is selected which would reduce the number of fields on the form considerably. However, if that's really not possible arrange them in separate areas (using group boxes or different background colours) and see if you can grey out the inactive fields.

Other things you could look for:

- Collapse the address fields and have a zip code/postal code lookup field to fill out the values for the user.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to splitting the form into Common/Subscriber/Contributor fields, you might want to use color hints. Use two light background colors for subscriber and contributor fields. Move the Subscriber/Contributor selection directly after the common fields, and use a light grey foreground color for the text boxes that are not applicable. (Of course, they *should* be disabled, but that's your managers stubbornness).

For the "additional" fields such as "Add. Email", you might want to use a smaller font. This serves as a visual hint that they're commonly skipped.